# Issue with this xsl template to calculate max for node list

Tags: xslt

The below for-each loop is only picking up first value for X.. and not actually finding maximum could you please let me know the issue here.

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//X">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
           <xsl:value-of select="abc:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'v1t1', abc:normalize_string($_XDOCTX, (.//.)[1]))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="abc:nOne(abc:normalize_string($_XDOCTX, (.//.)[1])) > number(abc:get_variable($_XDOCTX, 'v1t1'))">
           <xsl:value-of select="abc:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'v1t1', abc:normalize_string($_XDOCTX, (.//.)[1]))"/>
        </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You need to sort the nodes, so that the node with the maximum value is at `position() = 1`.

Comment: Thanks Michael for replying, but i dont think i can use xsl:sort, since i need to specify data-type as number and it rounds off numbers greater than 14 digits. Is there any other way to make this template work.

Comment: **1.** Are you using XSLT 1.0? If yes, there is no way to get the maximum value other than sorting the nodes (unless your processor happens to support an extension max() function). **2.** Please post a small example of the input - see [mcve].

Comment: <G_1>
    <G_2>
        <X>123456789.0123456780</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456781</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456782</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456783</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456784</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456785</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456786</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456787</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456788</X>
        <X>123456789.0123456789</X>
    </G_2>
</G_1>

Comment: Pleas don't post code in comments. Add this to your question and show the expected result, too.

Answer (score 1):

To sort such large sequences of digits numerically, you can split them into substrings and sort by each substring individually - for example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>123456789.0123456780</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456781</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456782</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456783</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456784</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456785</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456786</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456787</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456788</item>
    <item>123456789.0123456789</item>
    <item>123456789.012344</item>
    <item>123456789.012346</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(., '.')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="concat('0.', substring-after(., '.'))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <item>123456789.012346</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456789</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456788</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456787</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456786</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456785</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456784</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456783</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456782</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456781</item>
  <item>123456789.0123456780</item>
  <item>123456789.012344</item>
</output>
```

Note that the limitation is processor-dependent: I could not reproduce the problem using either [Xalan](http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFQ) or [Saxon](http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFQ/1).